# Using print() function in copy constructor C++

Tags: c++, reference, copy

The task is to create class, which counts the objects of its type, in every moment. Here is my code. The errors are:
1. the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "counter::print";
2. return value type does not match the function type; - this was obwious really!
I corrected the errors and it gives me new one that I can't fix;
1. 'void counter::print(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const counter' to 'counter &'

```
class counter {
private:
    static int count;
public:
    counter();
    counter(const counter &from);
    void print() const;
    ~counter();
};
counter::counter() {
    ++count;
}
counter::counter(const counter &from) {
    ++count;
    cout << "Copy constructor:\t";
    from.print(); // here is the error
}
void counter::print() const{
    cout << "\t Number of objects = " << count << endl;
}
counter::~counter() {
    --count;
    cout << "Destructor:\t\t";
    print();
}
int counter::count = 0;
counter f(counter x);
void main() {
    counter c;
    cout << "After constructing of c:";
    c.print();
    cout << "Calling f()" << endl;
    f(c);
    cout << "After calling f():";
    c.print();
}
counter f(counter x) {
    cout << "Argument inside f():\t";
    x.print();
    return x;
}
```

Comment: `return x;` as `void`?

Comment: So you have fixed the errors pointed out below.  When you say  'void counter::print(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const counter' to 'counter &'  Exactly *where* does it say this>

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, change:

```
void print();
```

to:

```
void print() const;
```

because (a) it's a `const` method anyway and (b) you're trying to call it in a `const` context within your constructor.

For the second error here:

```
void f(counter x) {
    cout << "Argument inside f():\t";
    x.print();
    return x; // 2 - nd error
}
```

it should be fairly obvious that you can't return a value from a `void` function. Either change it to:

```
counter f(counter x) {
    cout << "Argument inside f():\t";
    x.print();
    return x;
}
```

or simply don't return anything:

```
void f(counter x) {
    cout << "Argument inside f():\t";
    x.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `void print();`

You have declared a non-const member function, which means it cannot be called by const instances.

> `from.print(); // 1 - st error`

Here the type of `from` is `const counter&` which means it cannot call the `print` function. Instead make your `print` function const.

```
void print() const;
void counter::print() const { ... }
```

> `return x; // 2 - nd error`

Why are you returning anything from a function with a `void` return type?